# How do I make Twitter Bootstrap Responsive with Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, asset-pipeline

I'm using the bootstrap-sass gem with my Ruby on Rails site. I would like to make my layout responsive, so I tried adding `@import "twitter/bootstrap/responsive"` to various files, but all I got was a message which said:

> File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap/responsive.
>   Load path: Sass::Rails::Importer(site_path/app/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap_and_overrides.css.scss)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`@import "bootstrap-responsive";` as it is told in the [bootstrap-sass documentation](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/tree/2.1-stable#responsive-styling) for version 2. This was dropped in bootstrap-sass version 3 which is always responsive.

Comment: The web page of your hyperlink does not currently contain the word "responsive" on it anywhere, and this import does not seem to be working for me.  I'm guessing that something has changed, and as best I can tell this particular gem doesn't currently contain support for responsive.  I wish I could provide more info.

Comment: Bootstrap 3 is responsive by default. http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#disable-responsive This question was about Bootstrap 2.